# How to use $.get method in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in my view to hit one ActionResult

```
 ClearFilters = function () {
        $.get("/Mandate/Index/1");
        window.location.href = '<%=Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>';
    }
```

My controller Method

```
Public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
     //some code
}
```

with this Code I am able to hit Index Action Result but I am not getting int id value 1?

is that something I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined the routing for this type of request?

Comment: Yes I have it. it was working before but not now.

Comment: This smells like a routing problem.  Can you post your route definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. See if you get the id value, keeping all other code same.

```
$.get("/Mandate/Index", { id=1 }, success: function(){
   window.location.href = '<%=Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>';   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shanker Still I am not getting the value of id.. in my controller Action. thanks

Comment: Why are you setting the `location.href` right after $.get call. Can you do this in the success handler of `$.get`?